# Bash IO Redirection - Peculiar Filename with \r\n

Tags: bash, redirect, awk, io

I am extracting some information from a large file and directing the output to another file as below,

```
awk '{if ($1=="Multiple"); print $3}' file_01.txt > results.txt
```

When I put the above line in files.sh and execute it using bash command, strangely I find the resultant file name was not `results.txt` but `results.txt\r\n`

Is there anyway I could eliminate the trailing `\r\n` from the filename ?

When I tested the awk line in terminal I get the correct filename without the carriage return and line feed.

In **`echo`** command there is option `-n` to solve this but could not find any for awk.

Hope you can assist to shed some light.

p/s: As I have to extract information from many large files, I am stacking all the awk command in a bash file for ease of execution.

**Update 26 Mar 2014**

Thanks for your guidance.

1. Would like to confirm the content of file_01.txt indeed have \r\n (carriage return and line feed pair) and was generated from a Windows machine. The file then was ported to Ubuntu 10.04 for further post-processing.
2. As Ubuntu 10.04 does not have dos2unix, used fromdos (tofrodos package), tried the below syntaxes.

> ```
> fromdos file_01.txt
> fromdos -d file_01.txt
> fromdos < file_01.txt > fromdos_output.txt
> ```

All of the above still generate filename with \r\n i.e `results.txt\r\n`

Does the content of a file (lines with \r\n) affects filenaming in Ubuntu machine?

Comment: Your `file_01.txt` has carriage return. Run it through `dos2unix` utility before running `awk`.

Comment: Any chance you have moved your files between Windows and *nix?  If so use `dos2unix`/`unix2dos` to fix the line delimiter differences

Comment: You could start by using unix line endings for unix shellscripts

Comment: jaypal, DigitalTrauma and Eugen -- Have updated my writeup with results of new experiments. Used fromdos as Ubuntu 10.04 is said does not have dos2unix. Eugen, do you mean to find means to replace <CR><LF> with <EOL>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this. 
I did `fromdos` the bash file and it no longer produces filename with `\r\n` anymore.
Thanks for your hints.